# check if file exists, case sensitive in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, case-sensitive

What is a good way to check that a file exists with case sensitivity in C on Windows?

I have got this to work by comparing the filename with the all the file entries in the directory of the filename.  Is there a more efficient method in C?

Comment: See the [FindFirstFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) function.

Comment: Why?  You will almost certainly be [creating a TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) by doing this.  Doing any action X to see if some other action Y would work is a bad idea. Just because X works at the exact time you tried it, that doesn't mean Y will work later.  So when you try to do Y later, you still have to write all the error handling code you would have written by not doing X in the first place.  Because X is not Y, they're not the same and different rules ***will*** apply to the different actions.

Comment: Windows file system isn't case sensitive, so... I'm not sure you can do this.

Comment: And if the file system the file is on is not case-sensitive, the file named "ASDF" ***is*** the file named "asdf".

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes on Windows "ASDF" **is** the file named "asdf", but for some reason (valid or not, we don't know the details) the OP needs to know if the file exists with the exact casing.

Comment: @tim That's incorrect. NTFS is case-sensitive. It's Windows' file I/O system that's case-insensitive, unless specifically asked not to be (such as by using the `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` flag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATAA FindFileData;
HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(filenametocheck, &FindFileData);
```

now `FindFileData.cFileName` contains the filename as it is stored in NTFS.

All you need to do is compare `filenametocheck` with `FindFileData.cFileName`.

Don't forget to close the `h` handle with `FindClose(h)` and do error checking.

This works only for checking in the current directory, if `filenametocheck` contains a path (e.g `..\somefile.txt`, or `C:\\Somedir\Somefile.txt`) you need to do some more work.

For further details read the documentation of [`FindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-win32_find_dataa) and possibly look into [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/listing-the-files-in-a-directory).

Be aware that depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve, this may cause a [TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) as mentioned in a comment.